# Facebook Feed Dialog showing error

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have integrated facebook sdk with my native android app.
Currently i am trying to open facebook feed dialog from base adapter class and it is showing me error.
I have taken reference from the below link.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/feed-dialog
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/

Everytime it shows me different errors .[image]

[image]

I don't know what's wrong with my code.
I am also putting my code here.

```
 private void publishFeedDialog() {
        Bundle params = new Bundle();
        params.putString("name", "Facebook SDK for Android");
        params.putString("caption", "Build great social apps and get more installs.");
        params.putString("description", "The Facebook SDK for Android makes it easier and faster to develop Facebook integrated Android apps.");
        params.putString("link", "https://developers.facebook.com/android");
        params.putString("picture", "https://raw.github.com/fbsamples/ios-3.x-howtos/master/Images/iossdk_logo.png");

        WebDialog feedDialog = (
                new WebDialog.FeedDialogBuilder(CONTEXT,
                        Session.getActiveSession(),
                        params))
                .setOnCompleteListener(new WebDialog.OnCompleteListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(Bundle values,
                                           FacebookException error) {
                        if (error == null) {
                            // When the story is posted, echo the success
                            // and the post Id.
                            final String postId = values.getString("post_id");
                            if (postId != null) {
                                Toast.makeText(CONTEXT,
                                        "Posted story, id: " + postId,
                                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            } else {
                                // User clicked the Cancel button
                                Toast.makeText(CONTEXT,
                                        "Publish cancelled",
                                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        } else if (error instanceof FacebookOperationCanceledException) {
                            // User clicked the "x" button
                            Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),
                                    "Publish cancelled",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        } else {
                            // Generic, ex: network error
                            Toast.makeText(CONTEXT,
                                    "Error posting story",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }
                })
                .build();
        feedDialog.show();
    }
```

Comment: Try this, Go to the Facebook App. Edit its settings. On the Advanced settings page, disable the "Stream post URL security" option. I don't know whether this will work or not but just give a try.

Comment: ok let me try and let you know .

Comment: my key hash is same so i dont think there is a problem of key hash

Comment: are you using facebook's sample code??

Comment: @RiddhiShah, have you tried the solution which i have posted???

Comment: @InnocentKiller i cant find the "Stream post URL security"

Comment: Go to https://developers.facebook.com/apps

On the left hand side, click your app to select it.

Next to the "Settings" section in the middle column, there's an "Edit Settings" link. Click that.

On the new page, under the "Settings" menu on the left hand side, click "Advanced".

Under the "Migrations" section, find "Stream post URL security". Set it to "Disabled".

Click the "Save Changes" button at the bottom of the screen.

Comment: @Maulik.J yeah i am using sample code. basically i want to use feed dialog to post on my friend's wall and i know i just need to enter to and from field but even a simple feed dialog is not opening so i am quite worried.

Comment: @InnocentKiller thanks and i am trying. and let u know

Comment: can you do one thing create new project and register the same on facebook and copy entire class in your project because in sample code keyhash is wrong i was facing the same problem and this way i solved the same

Comment: @InnocentKiller hey it is working fine and now i am trying to post on my friend's wall I hope it works.

Comment: @InnocentKiller I am not able to post on my friend's wall. now what to do?

Comment: May be there is some other problem in your code as well. Do one thing ask new question and post your full code in it and give me link in comment. will try and let you know. Why i am telling you to post a new question is, because if you post a new question then some other also can answer...

Comment: @InnocentKiller hey it started working. If I am posting my another friend's wall then its working and sometimes its not working. yeah I am posting another question.

Comment: @InnocentKiller here is a link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21526783/feed-dialog-sometimes-not-posting-on-friends-wall

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this, Go to the Facebook App. Edit its settings. On the Advanced settings page, disable the "Stream post URL security" option.

How to go.

Go to [developers.facebook.com/apps](http://developers.facebook.com/apps) On the left hand side, click your app to select it.

Next to the "Settings" section in the middle column, there's an "Edit Settings" link.

Click that. On the new page, under the "Settings" menu on the left hand side, click "Advanced".

Under the "Migrations" section, find "Stream post URL security". Set it to "Disabled". Click the "Save Changes" button at the bottom of the screen..

It will look something like this

[image]

You can see by default this is on just click it OFF and click on Save Changes and then try to clean your project and run it again. Might be this will help you.

Comment: If it's worked then please accept the answer, so other time if someone is facing same problem like you so they can solve the problem without wasting his/her time. Thank you.